# Vb.Net and CSV files

Tags: vb.net, oracle10g

I have a VB.Net app that should enable the user to import CSV file into the datagrid (which it does) and then update those rows to a table in Oracle.

Here is what I have so far but it doesn't seem to work neither throw an error.

```
Private Sub Update_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As
   System.EventArgs) Handles Update.Click

    MsgBox("Saving...")

    Dim table As New DataTable()
    Dim BindingSource As New BindingSource()
    BindingSource.DataSource = table


    table.Columns.Add("ORDER_NO")
    table.Columns.Add("LINE_ITEM_NO")
    table.Columns.Add("CONTRACT")
    table.Columns.Add("PART_NO")
    table.Columns.Add("QTY_REQUIRED")
    table.Columns.Add("QTY_PER_ASSEMBLY")
    table.Columns.Add("RELEASE_NO")
    table.Columns.Add("SEQUENCE_NO")
    table.Columns.Add("ORDER_CODE")
    table.Columns.Add("PART_OWNERSHIP")

    Dim parser As New FileIO.TextFieldParser("C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\solution.csv")

    parser.Delimiters = New String() {","} ' fields are separated by comma
    parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True 
    parser.TrimWhiteSpace = True


    parser.ReadLine()



Dim sConnectionString As String = "Data
Source=MYSERVER.COM;User ID=MYNAME;Password=MYPASSWD;"

Dim strSql As String = "INSERT INTO SHOP_MATERIAL_ALLOC_TAB(ORDER_NO,
LINE_ITEM_NO, CONTRACT, PART_NO, QTY_REQUIRED, QTY_PER_ASSEMBLY,
RELEASE_NO,SEQUENCE_NO,ORDER_CODE,PART_OWNERSHIP) VALUES (@ORDER_NO,
@LINE_ITEM_NO,@CONTRACT,@PART_NO,@QTY_REQUIRED,@QTY_PER_ASSEMBLY,@RELEASE_NO,@SEQUENCE_NO,@ORDER_CODE,@PART_OWNERSHIP)"


    Using conn As New OracleClient.OracleConnection(sConnectionString)

        Dim adapter As New OracleDataAdapter
        Dim cmd As New OracleClient.OracleCommand()
        cmd.Connection = conn

        cmd.Connection.Open()
        cmd.CommandText = strSql
        adapter.InsertCommand = New OracleCommand(strSql, conn)
        adapter.UpdateCommand = cmd
        adapter.Update(table)

        '--cmd.ExecuteReader()
        cmd.Connection.Close()

        MsgBox("Saved! Kindly check your Shop order!")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing





    End Using

End Sub
```

**Now I have brought it down to inserting records in the table, but problem is it only parses the first column in the row. 
So all suppose 6 columns in the table are updated with values from the first field in the CSV.**

```
    MsgBox("Saving...")


    Dim parser As New FileIO.TextFieldParser("C:\Documents and Settings\nUser\Desktop\solution.csv")

    parser.Delimiters = New String() {","} ' fields are separated by comma
    parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True
    parser.TrimWhiteSpace = True

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1


        Dim CurrentField = parser.ReadFields()
        '--parser.ReadLine()

Dim sConnectionString As String = "Data Source=MYSERVER.COM;User ID=MYUSER;Password=MYPASSWD;"

Dim strSql As String = "INSERT INTO SHOP_MATERIAL_ALLOCT(ORDER_NO, LINE_ITEM_NO, CONTRACT, PART_NO, QTY_REQUIRED, QTY_PER_ASSEMBLY) VALUES (:ORDER_NO,           :LINE_ITEM_NO,:CONTRACT,:PART_NO,:QTY_REQUIRED,:QTY_PER_ASSEMBLY)"




        Using conn As New OracleClient.OracleConnection(sConnectionString)
            Using cmd As New OracleClient.OracleCommand()


                Dim adapter As New OracleDataAdapter
                conn.Open()
                cmd.Connection = conn
                cmd.CommandText = strSql
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ORDER_NO", CurrentField(i))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LINE_ITEM_NO", CurrentField(i))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CONTRACT", CurrentField(i))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PART_NO", CurrentField(i))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("QTY_REQUIRED", CurrentField(i))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("QTY_PER_ASSEMBLY", CurrentField(i))



                cmd.CommandText = strSql
                adapter.InsertCommand = New OracleCommand(strSql, conn)
                adapter.UpdateCommand = cmd
                'adapter.Update(table)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cmd.Connection.Close()

                DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
            End Using
        End Using
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Never used oracle so please ignore me if I'm being stupid.

Have you tried `conn.Connect()` rather than `cmd.Connection.Open()`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the part of your code that create a DataTable and add columns.
It's not used anywhere, so is not related to your issue.
Let's look at code relating data connection

```
' If I remember well, the parameters in an oracle statement are prefixed by a ":" 
Dim strSql As String = "INSERT INTO SHOP_MATERIAL_ALLOC_TAB(ORDER_NO," +
                       "LINE_ITEM_NO, CONTRACT, PART_NO, QTY_REQUIRED, QTY_PER_ASSEMBLY, " +
                       "RELEASE_NO,SEQUENCE_NO,ORDER_CODE,PART_OWNERSHIP) VALUES (:ORDER_NO, " +
                       ":LINE_ITEM_NO,:CONTRACT,:PART_NO,:QTY_REQUIRED,:QTY_PER_ASSEMBLY, " +
                       ":RELEASE_NO,:SEQUENCE_NO,:ORDER_CODE,:PART_OWNERSHIP)" 

' Connection and Command are Disposable, so use `Using` around them
Using conn As New OracleClient.OracleConnection(sConnectionString) 
Using cmd As New OracleClient.OracleCommand() 

     Dim adapter As New OracleDataAdapter 
     conn.Open()
     cmd.Connection = conn 
     cmd.CommandText = strSql 
     ' Now you need to add the parameters to your command
     ' One parameter for each column used in the insert statement
     ' I suppose that values for the paramenter are in the current line from your CSV
     cmd.Parameters.Add("ORDER_NO", OracleType.VarChar).Value = parser[index_of_orderNumber_Text]) 
     ' .... other parameters to be added....
     ' Now you can execute the INSERT statement directly with your command
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 
 End Using
```

And, as last thing, the OracleClient namespace has been deprecated by Microsoft, so you should try to replace with ODP directly from Oracle.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistakes Steve. I corrected the same but it gives me a warning about .Add being deprecated and obsolete and gives me the suggestion to use AddWithValue instead which I did - 

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ORDER_NO", parser[0]) but it throws an error "Identifier expected" and points to where the index value is supplied. Not much documentation on this, please guide me.

Comment: Sorry, I have made a mistake in my example. `cmd.Parameters.Add("ORDER_NO", OracleType.VarChar).Value = parser[0];` For the AddWithValue, I can't say. It should works as you have written. Try the old method (corrected)

Comment: this is the [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.100).aspx) to the documentation for the OracleClient from Microsoft.

Comment: The parser.ReadFields returns an array of string. You get always the same field (i) when instead you should choose the field corrisponding to your paramenter (0,1,2,3 etc), then you set the DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing inside the loop and this probably wreak havoc with your loop.

Comment: Yes, ReadField is my downfall. Any other function available which can enable me to fetch columns/parameters based on their index value?

There's ReadLine but that wont do either.

Comment: Steve - please assist me in this, how can I read it column by column?